# Можно ли сделать связку WordPress и фронт на Vue?

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

День добрый

Хочу соединить WordPress и Vue, и в теории вроде это возможно, но информации найти не могу

Может кто уже делал, дайте инструкцию)

Answer (score 0):

> Хочу соединить WordPress и Vue, и в теории вроде это возможно, но
> информации найти не могу

Можно. Но смысла в этом, ИМХО нет.

У WP есть [REST-API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) и его можно использовать в безголовой системе.

См например https://kinsta.com/blog/headless-wordpress/

Comment: Интересное предложение))не знал про это!) благодарю